# Integrating Factor Found by Inspection

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the equation:

$y(x^3 - y) dx - x(x^3 + y) dy = 0$

Solution:

Regroup the terms:

$x^3(y dx - x dy) = y(y dx + x dy)$

Then, substitute $d(xy)$ to $(y dx + x dy)$ since it is the exact differential form of $(y dx + x dy)$:

$x^3(y dx - x dy) = yd(xy)$

However, according to the book (Rainville, E. D., Bedient, P. E. (1989). Elementary Differential Equation. 7th Edition. New York: MacMillan Publishing Company), there are two exact differential form on the equation. The terms of the equation must be divided by $y^2$ to have an exact differential form, $d(\frac{x}{y})$, for $(y dx - x dy)$.

I don't know how $y^2$ obtained from the equation, $y(x^3 - y) dx - x(x^3 + y) dy = 0$, which can be used to have an exact differential equation for $(y dx - x dy)$. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^3(y dx - x dy) = yd(xy)$$
Divide by $y^2$ both sides. You have the right to do so. Multiply or divide both sides of an equation by the same quantity. The equality still holds. 
$$x^3d\frac x y = \frac {d(xy)}{y}$$
Divide by $x^2y$ :
$$ \frac x y d\frac x y = \frac {d(xy)}{(xy)^2}$$
Integrate.
$$ \frac 12  \frac {x^2 }{y^2} =- \frac {1}{xy}+C$$
$$  {x^3 } +{2y}+C_1{xy^2}=0$$

---

**Edit1**

$$x^3(y dx - x dy) = yd(xy)$$
You can also choose to divide by $x^2$
$$-x^3d\frac y x = \frac {yd(xy)}{x^2}$$
Divide by $y^3$ :
$$-\frac {x^3}{y^3}d\frac y x = \frac {d(xy)}{x^2y^2}$$
Now you can integrate.

Comment: What do you mean "you have the right to do so"? Therefore, everytime there is a same scenario, I can just divide the terms of the equation by $x^2$ or $y^2$ since it will lead to a exact differential form?

Comment: It's an equation you can divide or multiply both sides by the same quantity the equality still holds. Here the book choose $y^2$ they could also choose $x^2$ but not sure the next step is going to be easier. @HYDR0GEN

Comment: I added some lines @HYDR0GEN

Comment: I think you can't divide $(ydx - xdy)$ by $x^2$, because it won't lead to an exact differential form of either $d(\frac{x}{y})$ or $d(\frac{y}{x})$.

Comment: You can. Just change the sign thats why I added a minus sign @HYDR0GEN  $(ydx−xdy) =-(xdy-ydx)$

Comment: I see. Thank You.

Comment: You're welcomed Hydrogen. You should do the calculations with $x^2$ and $y^2$ @HYDR0GEN You end with the same answer in both case